# Lua: how to read .INI (text format) file only even lines and keeping only the right-side of a line after specific character

Tags: lua

I'm not a LUA programmer but sometimes I have to deal with.

Please here my issue:

I have an .INI file that's a text simple text formatted file, in which each setting is written in 2 lines in this way (here below the format used):

```
[machine_readable_plugin_name]
(plugin_name.maker.tld),flag=0|Human Readable Plugin Name (Maker)
```

The file contains hundreds of couple of lines like the one here above.

For each couple of lines, I need to:
Avoid all the first lines that are containing the "[]", I don't need their content
And from the second line, get only what is coming after the Pipe character "|"

```
print(string.match(s, "|(.*)"))
```

Returns me an empty string.
"s" contains the file's line I'm reading it by a "FOR END" cycle in which the above line code is in it.
By using `print(s)` I got all the lines printed out

What I need, is to get for each couple of line, the `print()` should return

```
Human Readable Plugin Name (Maker)
```

So, if the .INI contains 20 lines, I need to get 10 times

```
Human Readable Plugin 1 Name (Maker 1)
Human Readable Plugin 2 Name (Maker 2)
Human Readable Plugin 3 Name (Maker 3)
...
...
Human Readable Plugin 10 Name (Maker 10)
```

NOTE: the .INI file is not made by me. It's with the application and I can't modify it's format. It is what it is.

**EDIT 1**

Please here the code you kindly asked into the comments

```
local path_ = 'K:/APP_NAME/settings-win64.ini'
local handle_ = io.open(path_, "r")

for _ in handle_:lines() do
    s = handle_:read("*l")
    print(s) -- this output is ok. All lines are printed

    if _ == nil then 
        handle_:close() 
      else
     
        if s ~= nil then 
          human_Name = string.match(s, "|(.+)$")
          print("TEST") -- this one is printed out as expected.
          print(s) -- this one is printed out as expected.
          print(human_Name) -- this one is empty. Nothing is printed.
        end
    end -- if 1
  end -- for
```

Comment: Your line `print(string.match(s, "|(.*)"))` is correct.  The error is somewhere else.  You should show your code.

Comment: @ESkri I tried several ways I can't figure out what I'm making wrong.
I updated the post, including the code. I tried also with the $ but nothing is printed

Comment: The code isn't great, but it appears to work: `print(human_Name)` works for me, with an *.ini* file created [based on your format example](https://pastebin.com/ku4STK6d). Can you post a more exact example of the file? What version of Lua are you running?

Comment: @ESkri I tried with your .INI example. the strange thing is that:
With the real .INI I got the "nil" into the variable, while with your one, I get this:
´(plugin_name.maker.tld),flag=0|Human Readable Plugin Name (Maker) (with all lines so in total 4 lines)´.
Instead of to get only the right-side of the string: 
´Human Readable Plugin Name (Maker4)´.
About the LUA version: it's embedded into the application. not clue which version did they used.

Comment: @ESkri for the LUA interpreter, i wrote to the support.  I hope they will answer. If to you my code is working and to me not, it's something about it, I guess

Comment: TormyVanCool - You are probably speaking to @Oka , not me.

Comment: @ESkri oops, I'm sorry

Comment: For Lua 5.0 and later: If the base library is open, then the global variable [`_VERSION`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-_VERSION) holds a string indicating the version (e.g., `'Lua 5.4'`).

Comment: @Oka thank you so much for the suggestion. I solved the issue however with your suggestion I got the version: Lua 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All anomalies were generated within this couple of lines:

```
for _ in handle_:lines() do
    s = handle_:read("*l") <--- this line was the main issue generator
```

LUA was reading the file and it was reading it 2 times, creating all the issues I faced-out.

By removing the the second line, and modifying the code accordingly, everything started working fine. Also with the test file published by @Oka in the comments here below

```
local path_ = 'K:/APP_NAME/settings-win64.ini'
local handle_ = io.open(path_, "r")

for _ in handle_:lines() do
    --s = handle_:read("*l")
    print(_) -- this output is ok. All lines are printed

    if _ == nil then 
        handle_:close() 
      else
     
        if s ~= nil then 
          human_Name = string.match(_, "|(.+)$")
          print("TEST") -- this one is printed out as expected.
          print(_) -- this one is printed out as expected.
          print(human_Name) -- this one is empty. Nothing is printed.
        end
    end -- if 1
  end -- for
```